# How to test Rate this app functionality before submitting to app store

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi How I can test Rate this app functionality.I tried this code

```
 NSLog(@"gotoReviews");
    NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str];
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@APP_ID", str];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

In the code APP_ID is apple id from store.But how can I get and test before submitting to app store?Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this code before submitting to app store, but you need to do a few things.

1. Go to apple developer portal(developer.apple.com)
   Create Certificate, Provision, App Id
2. Go to Itunesconnect(itunesconnect.apple.com)
   Then you need to open My apps/New App

Create new app with the app id you have created at developer portal.

Once it has done, it will provide app id that you can input there and it is still your app not submitted yet.

Comment: Bundle Id  in ituens connect should be same as app id in developer portal?

Comment: Hi I tried that but am getting a blank screen not the review screen or anything.Could you please help me?

Comment: Yes bundle id should be same. and you are having blank screen because your app is not published yet. Also as long as you are using correct app id there, it should work and it is okay to pass as it has tested.

Comment: Thankyou.Using bundleId same as app id am I able to see some review screen before the app is published?

Comment: No you can't because that app has not published yet and there's no review.

Comment: ok so after the app is published I have to replace that app id in code then it will work..With this itunes connect app id can we submit to app store?

Comment: if you replaced the app id from itunesconnect, you can submit