# How to get iTunes Connect id before publish app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I write the following codes in my app:

```
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

Users can open the url of my app in App Store, and then they can rate stars.
But I don't know my iTunes Connect id, because I've not publish it yet. How can I deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101475/how-to-test-rate-this-app-functionality-before-submitting-to-app-store/29101679#29101679

Comment: Yes, it's the same question. tks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign in to iTunes Connect and create your app. There is no need to upload a build. When you create your app in iTunes Connect you will get tha appId (the id you want).

Once you create your app in iTunes Connect, you can get your id in the About this app section.
[image]